# VS2010 WebSetup not assigning AppPool to application during installation

Tags: vb.net, iis, web-setup-project

following code helps me configuring my IIS to setup an ApplicationPool and assign my WebApplication to it (using InstallerClass) successfuly when I compiled my projects under VS2005.

Now I'm having troubles while compiling under VS2010!
When I'm running my installation setup, I become now a DropDownList to choose an application pool for the site (I did not hav this before) and in the list there is not my AppPool that I'm creating.

The AppPool will be created after the installation, I can see it, but my application is not bind to it.

Have anyone an idea about what am I missing?
thanks much for helping.
Greets,
amine

PS: code:

```
Private Const _appPoolName As String = "MyPool001"

Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
    MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
    SetIISApplicationPool(_appPoolName, Me.Context)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub SetIISApplicationPool(ByVal AppPoolName As String, ByVal context As System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext)
    Dim targetSite As String = context.Parameters("targetsite")
    Dim targetVDir As String = context.Parameters("targetvdir")
    Dim targetDirectory As String = context.Parameters("targetdir")

    If targetSite Is DBNull.Value Then
        Throw New System.Configuration.Install.InstallException("IIS Site Name Not Specified!")
    End If

    If targetSite.StartsWith("/LM/") Then
        '// Sets the virtual directory to .NET 2.0
        targetSite = targetSite.Substring(4)
        Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo
        info.FileName = IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"), "Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe")
        info.Arguments = String.Format("-s {0}/ROOT/{1}", targetSite, targetVDir)
        info.CreateNoWindow = True
        info.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.Start(info)
        Try
            CreateApplicationPool("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools", AppPoolName)
        Catch : End Try
        Try
            AssignVDirToAppPool("IIS://localhost/" & targetSite & "/Root/" & targetVDir, AppPoolName)
        Catch : End Try
    End If
End Sub
Private Shared Sub CreateApplicationPool(ByVal strMetabasePath As String, ByVal strAppPoolName As String)
    Try
        If strMetabasePath.EndsWith("/W3SVC/AppPools") Then
            Dim blExists As Boolean = AppPoolExists(strMetabasePath, strAppPoolName)
            If blExists = False Then
                Dim objNewPool As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
                Dim objAppPools As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(strMetabasePath)
                objNewPool = objAppPools.Children.Add(strAppPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool")
                objNewPool.CommitChanges()
            End If

        Else
            Throw New Exception("Application pools can only be created in the */W3SVC/AppPools node.")
        End If
    Catch exError As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Failed in CreateAppPool with the following exception: " & exError.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Shared Sub AssignVDirToAppPool(ByVal strMetabasePath As String, ByVal strAppPoolName As String)
    Try
        Dim objVdir As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(strMetabasePath)
        Dim strClassName As String = objVdir.SchemaClassName.ToString()
        If strClassName.EndsWith("VirtualDir") Then
            Dim objParam As Object() = {0, strAppPoolName, True}
            objVdir.Invoke("AppCreate3", objParam)
            objVdir.Properties("AppIsolated")(0) = "2"
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Only virtual directories can be assigned to application pools")
        End If
    Catch exError As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Failed in AssignVDirToAppPool with the following exception: " & exError.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Shared Function AppPoolExists(ByVal strMetabasePath As String, ByVal strAppPoolName As String) As Boolean
    strMetabasePath += "/" & strAppPoolName
    Dim blExists As Boolean = False
    If System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Exists(strMetabasePath) = True Then
        blExists = True
    End If
    Return blExists
End Function
```